# Standalone remote desktop as good as VMware View PCoIP or Citrix XenDesktop HDX

Tags: remote-desktop, vmware-view, xendesktop

Is there a standalone (point-to-point), remote desktop software for Windows (Win7/Server 2008 R2) that has graphics and audio quality of VMware Views PCoIP solution or Citrix XenDesktops HDX?  In simple terms, is there something like VNC that's got REALLY good graphics and full duplex audio?

I've been evalutating both View and XenDesktop.  Both are good products, but not necessarily on a home budget.  View costs $1,500.  XenDesktop costs $500 (cost of licensing vSphere actually; XenDesktop Express is free).  Both solutions require 3 servers: a vCenter/XenCenter, an Active Directory domain controller, and the View Manager/Desktop Manager.  That's three whole server just to get high quality remote desktop viewing.

So, anything that doesn't require three servers between the host and the client?

Comment: what OS? there's some decent OS specific remote desktops

Comment: Windows: Server 2008 R2 and Win 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this one : 
[HDXConnect](http://community.citrix.com/display/ocb/2011/02/18/HDX+Connect+Demo+Is+Now+Available+Try+it+Out)

works like a dream ! Got it from my Citrix Partner

Comment: YES - or at least, it looks very good! Now how does one go about getting it?  Or is this still a not-yet-released product?

Answer (score 1):

Since the original post, [Teradici](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teradici) has come out with such a product: Remote Desktop access to a Windows machine (point to point) using PCoIP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a X based os, freenx or nomachine has excellent high quality remote desktop functionality that works well over the internet - it dosen't do sound tho

for windows, good old RDP does decent graphics, and sound.

Answer (score 0):

since your talking win7/w2k8r2 then get sp1 and do the remoteFX thing!

Comment: Because all my machines are virtualized on Vmware ESXi - which is free. I don't think I can use RemoteFX on Vmware.

Comment: sorry missed read things

Answer (score 0):

I've used HP RGS successfully, it's especially useful if you're running 3D software that demands heavy GPU usage in a remote machine or a VM with NVIDIA GRID. Otherwise, there's a project to get SPICE detached from qemu, but I'm no aware of how useful it is these days.